# Prove that the line is tangent to the curve at the point.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, curves

Hello can someone please walk me through part a and b of the below question? I really want to understand it but am having a hard time figuring out the solution.
I know how to calculate curvature for a parametrized and unparametrized curve using the respective formulas. Would I just take the derivatives of alpha, the respective cross products for the formula and simplify down to find the curvature? 
Thank you very much. [image]

Comment: a. can be proven by two easy steps. First prove that the points belongs to both the curve and the line by showing that it verifies their equation.

Then, show that $dy/dx$ of the curve and the line are equal at a.

Comment: What do you mean when it verifies their equation? Should we plug in the alpha(theta) points somewhere? I understand the dy/dx part. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the original question. I see that the curve is not given.

Comment: @pathahooligan right I am not sure what to do without the curve

Comment: @Unkle: It is from which text-book?

Comment: It's from Shifrin. Great book to self-study with difficult exercises, so it's great to learn and master the subject @Narasimham

Comment: @Unkle: How can we get Ted Shifrin to comment here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be understood that the polar coordinates are for the tangent point T or $ \alpha$ and not for the foot of perpendicular P.

I give a direct geometrical construction method based on differential lengths rather than a derivation.It is an attempt that is only partially successful,as of now, others may suggest improvements.

Separate sketch labels $(r, t) $ polar coordinate tangency point T and also $\phi$ and $\psi$.

From triangle OTX when external angle equated to sum of internal angles we get
 $$ t = \phi - \psi   ...(1*) $$

By consideration of differential triangles, we can mark differentials $ dL, dp, p d\theta$ and $ q dL. $

Also  $ d\theta = d \phi$ due to normal/tangent pair perpendicularity.

The radius r has components

$$ OP = p = r. sin \psi = dL/d\theta  ... (2*) $$ and,

$$ PT = q = -r. cos\psi = dp / d\theta  ...(3*) $$

along the normal and tangent respectively.

$$ x_T = p. cos\theta - q. sin \theta , y_T = p. sin\theta + q. cos \theta  ... (4*) $$ Proposition 7 a).

Derivative of (1*) with respect to arc results in curvature

$$ kg = d\psi/dL + sin \psi/r  ... (5*) $$

Plugging in from (2*) and (3*)

$$ kg= dp/dL/q        ... (6*) $$

which does not agree with required result.

Arc Length $ L = \int p. d\theta $ Proposition 7 c).

but Area = $\int (p^2 + q^2)/2. d\theta $ which also does not agree with desired result.

EDIT2:
The given result in proposition 7 d), if it does connote area in another way, most probably is a printing error of the sign.

[image: TgtToCurve]

EDIT1:

[image: TgtToCurv3]

The example of a circle radius a above x-axis may be considered as *counter-example* for Proposition 7 b).

$p = OV + VC + CT  = H/ sin \theta + h cos\theta  + a =  r\, sin \psi $

$ p' (\theta)  = - H\, csc \theta\,  cot \theta - h\, sin\theta $

$ p'' (\theta)  = - H\, csc\theta\,  ( csc^2\theta + cot^2\theta)  - h\, cos\theta  $

$  p  (\theta) +  p'' (\theta) = 2 H\, csc ^3\theta  + a $

which does not agree with 7 b) unless H=0.

Comment: Two tangential comments: (1) if you want to contact a moderator, please use a flag. (2) why should this be put on hold? (Ignoring the fact that putting a question on hold is something that, preferably, results from community actions [votes of 5 users].)

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks,learning on this site.. perhaps you consider deleting this.